# How to get .json files included in a build in Angular 4 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, webpack

In a directory `root/src/app/lsg/demo-parent`, I am including the following files:

```
demo-parent.module.ts
demo-parent.component.ts
demo-parent.component.spec.ts
demo-parent.component.html
demo-parent.component.scss
demo-parent.routing.ts
en.json
fr.json
```

I need access to the content that is in `en.json` and `fr.json` when the application is running.  I am using a third party library, `ngx-translate`, which is used for i18n/internationalization.  `ngx-translate` wants you to put all your `[lang].json` files in a main `root/src/assets/i18n` directory, but for our project we need the translation files to live in the same directories as the components.

If I do this in my `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "app"
  ],
```

(i.e. adding "app" to the assets array)
...then I can get to the `.json` files that live in each component directory.  But we don't want to expose `app` this way.

When I run `ng serve` and go to the devTools and look at "Sources", I can see the following lives in the `DemoParentModule` directory:

```
DemoParentComponent.html
DemoParentComponent.ngfactory.js
DemoParentComponent.ngfactory.js? [sm]
DemoParentComponent_Host.html
DemoParentComponent_Host.ngfactory.js
DemoParentComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]
module.ngfactory.js
module.ngfactory.js? [sm]
```

Everything I need is there...except the `.json` files.

**How can I get the `.json` files to be included in these directories when I run `ng serve`?**

Comment: I'd suggest moving the files to the assets folder or an alternate folder so you don't have to expose your `app` folder.

Comment: We don't want to expose the app folder, but we also don't want to have the files all living in one place.  We want the files to live with the components themselves.  The reason for this is some of these components are ultimately going to be added to an npm package and consumed by other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the `.json` file using http call. To request server resource better create a new service to read file. Then return the data as `observable` and register to it in your demo-parent `component`.

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class DataServices{

    constructor(private http: Http) {
         var obj;
    }

    public getEN(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get("./en.json")
                         .map((res:any) => res.json())
                         .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));

     }

    public getFR(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get("./fr.json")
                         .map((res:any) => res.json())
                         .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));

     }
}
```

**Component**

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DataServices} from './data-services';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<*.htm>`
})
export class DemoParentComponent {

  constructor(private service DataServices) {
  }

  init() {
      let subscription = this.service.getFR.subscripe((data)=>{
          console.log(data); 
     });
  }

}
```

Comment: Behind-the-scenes, ngx-translate is already making http calls.  The calls are being made successfully, but it 404s because it's just that the file isn't getting included in the build.